Difference between EVA (ethylene vinyl acetate) and VAE (vinyl ethylene acetate)
TL;DR
What the difference between VAE and EVA on molecular level?
I know that EVA is plastic that is waterproof and has a such molecular structure: 
But VAE is not waterproof (I've used RDP VAE, mixed it with water and dried) and gotten a film that is water soluble.
I read that PVA (polyvinyl acetate) glue is soluble because has PVC (polyvinyl alcohol) with the next structure  and because OH is soluble.
So my question is why VAE is water soluble and what is molecular structure?

The main difference is the monomer ratio. VAE has more of vinyl acetate then EVA and is more hydrophilic.

@Poutnik in this article said that their structure is defferent: https://www.elephchem.com/is-ethylene-vinyl-acetateeva-the-same-as-vinyl-acetate-ethylenevae. Also range of monomers ratio are pretty similar (5-50% vs 10-60%)

Different production technology and macro form VAE as adhesive suspension, EVA as solid plastic for hot melting. See also VAE dispersion polymer vs EVA hot melt. What's the difference? and vaepolymers - vae-vs-eva

@Poutnik there is no answer for my qustion. Also there is pure PVA plastic exists too
